# What does an exclamation mark before a function really mean in PHP

Tags: php, function, boolean

Just as in the title, what does an exclamation mark before a function really mean in PHP?

For example is the following statement:

```
if (!stripos($haystack, $needle)) {}
```

the same as this:

`if (stripos($haystack, $needle) === FALSE) {}`

or this:

`if (stripos($haystack, $needle) == FALSE) {}`

Any clarification would be appreciated

Comment: It means if it is not equall or the result is false. it is a short method of writing code

Comment: @Radu Maybe my question wasn't clear enough but I was asking whether ! before a function checks types or not.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `!` preceding the function is the same as...

```
if (stripos($haystack, $needle) == FALSE) {}
```

It's the same because it is a `==` comparison which doesn't check types.

It's called the *negation unary operator*. It *flips* the Boolean value (coercing to Boolean if need be) of a value.

For example...

```
! 0;    // True
! 1 ;   // False
! '';   // True
! true; // False
!! 0    // False
```

The `!!` trick is handy in languages without a `(bool)` cast. By flipping a value twice, you get the Boolean version of its original value.

Comment: Thanks, this is the clarification I was looking for

Comment: @alex, How did you know it coerce to boolean if need be? Did the docs meantion about it? http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: @Pacerier It says *TRUE if $a is not TRUE.*

Comment: @alex, Why does *"is not TRUE"* involve coercing? Isn't *"is not TRUE"* simply `!==` ?

Answer (score 0):

! will work on value comparison so it's same as the second comparison I think. because ! will catch false, 0, null as false, and they are not the same types as you see. "" may be an exception for that because I always use trim()!="" to compare the strings. I don't know about that.

Comment: ..And thanks for the appreciation. I'm trying to help here. Doesn't my answer make sense to you?

Comment: Your answer was good but alex's answer was for me easier to understand. Btw. It wasn't me who voted you down.

Comment: No I was commenting to another comment, sorry. he deleted after I wrote this.