# javascript validating in the wrong order

Tags: javascript, html, validation

```
function validateForm() {
    var name = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
    if (name == undefined || name == null || name == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }

    var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    if (name.match(letters)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('Name must have alphabet characters only');
        document.forms["myForm"]["name"].focus();
        return false;
    }
}

function validateForm() {
    var unit = document.forms["myForm"]["unit"].value;
    if (unit == undefined || unit == null || unit == "") {
        alert("Unit must be filled out");
        return false;
    }

    var alpha = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
    if (unit.match(alpha)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('User address must have alphanumeric characters only');
        document.forms["myForm"]["unit"].focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

The validation works but it starts from the unit field instead of the name, when I fill out the unit field with the right characters and submit it doesn't go back to validate the Name field, please need serious advice?

Comment: You have 2 functions with the same name, why ?

Comment: correction, he has ONE function, the second one only :p

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have 2 functions with the same name as the second one will override the first.  Merge the functions like so:

```js
function validateForm() {
    var formIsValid = true;
  
    var name = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
    if (name == undefined || name == null || name == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        formIsValid = false;
    } else  if (!name.match(/^[A-Za-z]+$/)) {
        alert('Name must have alphabet characters only');
        document.forms["myForm"]["name"].focus();
        formIsValid = false;
    }
  
    var unit = document.forms["myForm"]["unit"].value;
    if (unit == undefined || unit == null || unit == "") {
        alert("Unit must be filled out");
        formIsValid = false;
    } else if (!unit.match(/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
        alert('User address must have alphanumeric characters only');
        document.forms["myForm"]["unit"].focus();
        formIsValid = false;
    }
  
    return formIsValid;
}
```

Comment: Pete thanks a lot man, it works now why is there '!' next to the ids?

Comment: The exclamation mark means `not` so the if is if it doesn't match - it just removes the need for the returning the true from the if it does match.  [More info here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052719/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-before-a-function-really-mean-in-php)