# Why using operator in front of function?

Tags: php, operators

I started learning PHP 1 week ago, i'm making some form tests to get more apprehension on the language,  i get stuck in problem small problem for you guys....

I used in_array function from the PHP manuale to check an array off names at login

The function did not work to check the array tell i add `!in_array` !!!
Normal `in_array` did not work to check for names ...

So I used blaindly the operator "!" in front of the function, so why did it work with that operator and not without it ?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Forum</title>
    <meta name="Nic" content="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> </head>

<body>
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$names = array("Nicolaus", "Solo", "Yiu", "Yang", "Darius");
$minimum = 5;
$maximum = 10;
$username = $_POST['username'];
echo '<br>';
$password = $_POST['passwoard'];
if(strlen($username) < $minimum){
echo 'Username needs to be longer then 5 carcaters !';

}

if(strlen($username) > $maximum){
echo "Username can't be longer then 10 carcaters";
}
if(!in_array($username, $names)){
echo "You are not alowed , not in database !";
} else {
echo 'Welcome';
}

echo '<br>';
echo 'Your Username is : ' . "<b>" . $username . '</b>';
echo '  Your Password is : ' . "<b>" . $password . '</b>';
}

?>
        <form action="my_from.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
            <input type="password" name="passwoard" placeholder="password">
            <input type="submit" name="submit"> </form>
</body>
```

Ty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does an exclamation mark before a function really mean in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052719/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-before-a-function-really-mean-in-php)

Comment: Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: So i'm just confused, why i had to use "!" operator for the function in_array to work ?

Comment: Without !, what error will thrown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

! means NOT, its an operator to make comparisons when you want to check if something is false.

```
$raining = false;

if (!$raining){ 
    echo "its not raining"; 
}
```

Now that you posted your code:

```
if(!in_array($username, $names)){
    echo "You are not allowed , not in database !";
} else {
    echo 'Welcome';
}
```

`in_array` is a function that checks if some value is inside an array. You are testing if `$username` is inside `$names` array.
Your conditional checks if `$username` is NOT in array, if so, it means that `$username` is not allowed because it doesn't make part of the permitted `$names`.
Your `ELSE` clause identify that it is in the array, and then the user is able to login.

you can invert your logic:

```
if(in_array($username, $names)){
    echo 'Welcome';
} else {
    echo "You are not allowed , not in database !";
}
```

And it will work as well.

Comment: Thanks very much leo_ap i understand new ,i read function like this new :  if is not in_array variables then echo : Not alowed !

Answer (score 2):

`!` symbol is used for negating the logic of the function.

What you actually want to do is, you want to **reject** an user with `$username`, if his/her name is **NOT** in the `$names` array. You have got a function to check whether an element is present in an array. So adding `!` operator to it negates the logic.

```
if (!in_array($username, $names))
```

That means if the `$username` is **NOT** present in array `$names`.

Using `!` is similar to checking with condition `== FALSE`. But we can't directly use that logic on that function so we opted for `!` operator.

---

Another alternative for your example without `!` is,

```
if (in_array($username, $names)) {
    echo "Welcome";
} else {
    echo "You are not alowed , not in database !";
}
```

---

Hope this helps! :)