# ! Logical Operator and Scope in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm working through JavaScript Essential Training on Lynda.com and I am having a hard time wrapping my head around the logic of a concept.

I have this code below which sets a timer to run every thousandth of a second by setting an interval using setInterval.

```
var timerRunning = false;

function start() {
    let textEnteredLength = testArea.value.length;
    if (textEnteredLength === 0 && !timerRunning) { //textEnteredLength is 0 and timerRunning is false
        timerRunning = true;
        interval = setInterval(runTimer, 10); //runTimer every 10 milliseconds (thousandth of a second)
    }
}
```

Basically, I am confused because in the tutorial, timerRunning is a global variable set to false at the top of the code `(var timerRunning = false;)`

Therefore, doesn't `!timerRunning` mean that `timerRunning` is true? Or, is it because logically `!timerRunning` means not `timerRunning` AKA false regardless of what the global variable is set to initially?

**EDIT:**

Nevermind... I somehow misunderstood the logic of the code, apparently I need to sleep more. For some reason I was thinking `var timerRunning = false` set the value of timerRunning in the if statement, and therefore, `!timerRunning` would be true, when really `timerRunning` really just means false, and we continue to the inside of the if statement because the if statement is true.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: clearInterval perhaps?

Comment: if timerRunning is true, !timerRunning is false...

Comment: the question is about the logic of `timerRunning` variable, I think the title need to be changed since it is misleading. I don't know what the best title would be though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!timerRunning` is like `false == timerRunning` because of the exclamation mark. This is in every programing language AFAIK. Read more about it here: [What does an exclamation mark before a function really mean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10052735/2008111)

```js
var timerRunning = false;

console.log('false ... ' + timerRunning);
console.log('true cause it is false ... ' + !timerRunning);
```

Answer (score 0):

At first run of `start`, `timerRunning` is `false`, meaning `!timerRunning` is `true`.
The consequence is the `if`-block is run only once, the first time `start` is called.